# Album view in Clementine player ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, clementine

I need the album view like windows media player.how can i do that in Clementine player ?

[image: I need the below output how can i get this in clementine player ?]

Comment: Can you illustrate he desired layout with a screenshot, please? Otherwise only people with that particular knowledge of WMP can help you.

Comment: That particular view is simply not available in Clementine. The Cover Manager, as Elfy says, is the closest you can get?

Comment: i need this sample player like above ? which player have like that ?@muru

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get, I believe, is `Tools - Cover Manager`

You can Load or Add to Playlist from there.

Comment: let me try and come @elfy

Comment: pardon? that makes no sense to me in the slightest